# Jupyter Notebook: draw logic gates

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to avoid drawing logic gates with \LATEX and the accepted answer to this question [latex_logic_gates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32839/drawing-circuit-diagrams-with-logic-gates-in-latex).

So I wrote a python 3 Jupyter Book and wonder how to get logic gates into a Jupyter Notebook to print it in a book section?

Any ideas for frameworks: I am a total python 3 noob, just installed using pip3 in ubuntu - no anaconda or something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got a nice jupyter-notebook and finally I used anaconda to install python3 and jupyter-book.

Follow the steps here, Getting started and Logik Gates:

[Logik_Gates_Jupyter_Notebook](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/start.html)